# Switch between execution of two functions every few seconds

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm using Unity and C#. My game runs for infinite time,unless the player is destroyed.

How can I switch between execution of two functions every few seconds, for now I was using if statements, but I can't do that since the game runs forever and that would require infinite number of conditions.

I want to execute the code under these two if statements alternatively after few seconds.

So, how can I achieve that?

```
private void Update () 
{
    timeelapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log(timeelapsed);

    if (timeelapsed >= 20f && timeelapsed <= 40f)
    {
        LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
        CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);

    }
    if (timeelapsed > 40f && timeelapsed <= 60f)
    {
        CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
        LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show those if-statements? Edit them into your question

Comment: just added the if statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reset the `timeelapsed` variable:

```
void Update () {
    timeelapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log(timeelapsed);

    if (timeelapsed < 20f)
    {
        LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
        CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
        LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);
        if (timeelapsed >= 40f) timeelapsed = 0f;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the value of `timeelapsed`, you could do something like this instead:

```
int quotient = (int)timeelapsed / 20;
if (quotient % 2 == 0)
{
    LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
    CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);
}
else
{
    CurveSpawnerLeft.SetActive(false);
    LinearSpawnerLeft.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I want the 2nd set of statements to also execute for a while,i dont want to instantanously switch to 1st set again

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: I would change `if >= 40, timeelapsed = 0` to `if >= 40, timeelapsed -= 40` to avoid microtime adding up over a long period (your time will never be exactly 40, and any amount you trim off each cycle will add up). May not be important for the Asker, but might be for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be to use built-in Coroutine mechanism

```
WaitForSeconds waiter = new WaitForSeconds(20);
IEnumerator Start()
{
  while(true)
  {
   DoOneThing();
   yield return waiter;
   DoAnotherThing();
   yield return waiter;
 }
}
```